# 'Cannot find proj_api.h header' when deploying proj4rb on heroku using custom buildpacks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku, buildpack, proj

### Problem

I'm trying to install the ruby gem [proj4rb](https://rubygems.org/gems/proj4rb) on heroku, which requires the `proj_api` header files of the `PROJ.4` C library.

Pushing to heroku, I get the following error (only relevant lines shown):

```
    Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.
/tmp/build_2701eb422e13f4f8f7a20fe030059498/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for proj_api.h... no
extconf.rb:6:in `<main>': Cannot find proj_api.h header (RuntimeError)
extconf failed, exit code 1
Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2701eb422e13f4f8f7a20fe030059498/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/proj4rb-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/build_2701eb422e13f4f8f7a20fe030059498/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/proj4rb-1.0.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing proj4rb (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install proj4rb -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
Bundler Output: Fetching gem metadata from https://rubygems.org/...........

...

Gem::Ext::BuildError: ERROR: Failed to build gem native extension.

/tmp/build_2701eb422e13f4f8f7a20fe030059498/vendor/ruby-2.1.5/bin/ruby extconf.rb
checking for proj_api.h... no
extconf.rb:6:in `<main>': Cannot find proj_api.h header (RuntimeError)

extconf failed, exit code 1

Gem files will remain installed in /tmp/build_2701eb422e13f4f8f7a20fe030059498/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/gems/proj4rb-1.0.0 for inspection.
Results logged to /tmp/build_2701eb422e13f4f8f7a20fe030059498/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.1.0/extensions/x86_64-linux/2.1.0-static/proj4rb-1.0.0/gem_make.out
An error occurred while installing proj4rb (1.0.0), and Bundler cannot continue.
Make sure that `gem install proj4rb -v '1.0.0'` succeeds before bundling.
!
!     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
!
!     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

I know that building does happen on a special container and is then deployed to heroku. That's why I use buildpacks with the two buildpacks shown below, which include the . While Heroku compiles the ruby, I get the mentioned error.

It's confusing me a bit that running

```sh
heroku run bash
```

and then

```sh
gem install proj4rb
```

works without error. So I assume the installation of the buildpack *does* work and the headers *are* being found, this way.

### Question

What can be done to eliminate this issue? Is there a simple way—did I perhaps use the wrong geo-buildpack? Or do I have to write my own buildpack for ruby? Or is it just a matter of configuration of the `ruby-buildpack/geo-buildpack`?

Any help is kindly appreciated. Please let me know if output information is missing.

### Setting

I'm using the default [heroku getting-startet](https://github.com/heroku/ruby-getting-started.git) rails-project for better "reproducibility" with custom buildpacks.

`Gemfile`:

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

ruby '2.1.5'

# Bundle edge Rails instead: gem 'rails', github: 'rails/rails'
gem 'rails', '4.1.8'
# Use postgresql as the database for Active Record
gem 'pg'
gem 'rails_12factor', group: :production
# Use SCSS for stylesheets
gem 'sass-rails', '~> 4.0.3'
# Use Uglifier as compressor for JavaScript assets
gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.3.0'
# Use CoffeeScript for .js.coffee assets and views
gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 4.0.0'

# Use jquery as the JavaScript library
gem 'jquery-rails'
# Turbolinks makes following links in your web application faster. Read more: https://github.com/rails/turbolinks
gem 'turbolinks'
# Build JSON APIs with ease. Read more: https://github.com/rails/jbuilder
gem 'jbuilder', '~> 2.0'
# bundle exec rake doc:rails generates the API under doc/api.
gem 'sdoc', '~> 0.4.0',          group: :doc

# Spring speeds up development by keeping your application running in the background. Read more: https://github.com/rails/spring
gem 'spring',        group: :development

# Use unicorn as the app server
gem 'unicorn'

gem 'proj4rb', '~> 1.0.0'
```

`.buildpacks`:

```
https://github.com/cyberdelia/heroku-geo-buildpack.git#1.3
https://github.com/heroku/heroku-buildpack-ruby#v129
```